# Purging custom .deb package through script exits suddenly

Tags: bash, scripts, deb

I am a developer, who sometime works on deployment related things. I am using `Jenkins` to auto-deploy my application to an `ubuntu 14.04` machine. My application is packaged as `.deb` and some supporting apps as `jar`. I have written a small shell script to do the installation of debian/jar. I am trying to purge my existing application and install the new one. But sometimes, the script gets exited while purging and the remaining steps are not executed. This is creating some issues for me since many times I have to login to the server and re-install and restart my application.
I am not getting any errors in the console while executing it, so not able to provide any more information.

Pasting my script here, can someone point out what is the possible issue in my script.

```
mod=$1
defaultType="true"
isJar=${2:-$defaultType}
echo "before killing process mod: $1"
sudo pkill -f "${mod}-api"
echo "module ${mod}"
echo "after process kill"
cd /home/administrator/apps/

if [ ${isJar} = "false" ]
then
#       echo "Purging debian package"
#       sudo dpkg --purge ${mod}-api
        echo "Installing debian package"        
        sudo dpkg --install ${mod}-api*.deb
        sudo service ${mod}mod start
else
        jarfile=${mod}-api*.jar
        echo "$jarfile"
        nohup java -Dlogback.configurationFile="$mod-logback.xml" -jar ${jarfile} &>/dev/null &
fi
exit
```

I tried the solution provided by Thomas, but getting the below error :

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
Starting Common Module: Commonstart-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/bin/common-api (No such file or directory)
.
Selecting previously unselected package common-api.
(Reading database ... 177687 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack common-api_0.8.9.55-DEV-SNAPSHOT_all.deb ...
Unpacking common-api (0.8.9.55-DEV-SNAPSHOT) ...
dpkg: error processing archive 2 (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Setting up common-api (0.8.9.55-DEV-SNAPSHOT) ...
Creating system group: common-api
Creating system user: common-api in common-api with common-api daemon-user and shell /bin/false
Errors were encountered while processing:
 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made alterations to your script to make some logfiles.  And, some error handling so you just exit on one of the execution steps if it fails.  And some minor style stuff since I'm painfully evil with needing certain style things added.

Note that I make a dir in `/tmp/` called `custominstall-logs` to hold the logs here.  You can make that wherever you want, but I would suggest leaving it in `/tmp/` (so that if no errors happen, you have error logs).

I'm a little picky about style and other things, so I've changed a little of your script and added comments.  (I didn't add error checks for where your commented out 'purge the package' stuff is)

```
#!/bin/bash
mod=$1
defaultType="true"
isJar=${2:-$defaultType}
echo "before killing process mod: $1"
sudo pkill -f "${mod}-api"
echo "module ${mod}"
echo "after process kill"
cd /home/administrator/apps/

# Using an error checking folder in /tmp/... make it.
mkdir /tmp/custominstall-logs/

if [ ${isJar} = "false" ]
then
#       echo "Purging debian package"
#       sudo dpkg --purge ${mod}-api 2&>1 > /tmp/custominstall-logs/apt-log-purge
#       if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
#           echo "Error removing package; please refer to the log file "
#           echo "in /tmp/custominstall-logs/apt-log-purge for details."
#           exit 1   # Exit with an error code, instead of 0
#       fi 
        echo "Installing debian package"        
        sudo dpkg --install ${mod}-api*.deb 2&>1 > /tmp/custominstall-logs/apt-log-install
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error installing package; please refer to the log file "
            echo "in /tmp/custominstall-logs/apt-log-install for details."
            exit 2   # Exit with an error code, instead of 0
        fi 
        sudo service ${mod}mod start 2&>1 > /tmp/custominstall-logs/service-start-log
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error starting the service; please refer to the log file "
            echo "in /tmp/custominstall-logs/service-start-log for details."
            exit 3   # Exit with an error code, instead of 0
        fi 
else
        jarfile=${mod}-api*.jar
        echo "$jarfile"
        nohup java -Dlogback.configurationFile="$mod-logback.xml" -jar \
            ${jarfile} &>/dev/null &
fi

# If we didn't exit earlier with an error code, then we exit with
# Code 0 for "Success".
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed script and explanation. I am going to try this right away. :)

Comment: I tried that, but getting an error. Pasted that in as an update in question itself

Comment: @YaduKrishnan `dpkg` is running somewhere else then.  Automated updates, or whatever, are currently running - you can't run this while Update Manager, or `apt-get` or Synaptic or any other package management stuff is going on.  The script isn't at fault.

Comment: If I run the dpkg --install mypack.deb, it is not giving any error, but running through the script fails :(

Comment: @YaduKrishnan Then you have to read the output from the logs and debug your package.  It looks like your package is trying to access something that doesn't exist - time to check your package for errors and flaws.  (We didn't write your package, we can't *debug* your package)